# How to get how many times a product is sold?

Tags: magento2, product

I need to get the number of times a certain product is sold or ordered. I should show this in product page

Comment: means? please clear question?

Comment: I need to get the number of times a certain product is sold or ordered. I should show this in product page .  @AmitBera

Answer (score 0):

Probably the simplest way is to count orders / invoices containing the product. It's also probably the most accurate approach.

Comment: Can you give more details about this method, maybe some code.